# Higher frequency waves

Tags: energy, frequency, gamma-rays

Can we artificially create extremely high  frequency waves in the ( order of 10^60 )? how hard is it to create high frequency waves, and what limits are potential in doing so...

Comment: Why $10^{60}$? Is there something special about the exponent 60? Is this in units of Hz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably impossible, since the wavelength is 16 orders of magnitude smaller than the [Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length). From the [Planck–Einstein relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation), $E = h\nu$, a single such photon would have energy equivalent to about 7.4 million tonnes, and its [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) would be about $10^{-17} m$, much larger than the wavelength, thus the photon would be a black hole.

It's probably impossible to pack that much energy into such a tiny space. The universe *might* have acheived that sort of energy at the very start of the Big Bang, but I expect that quantum effects prohibited that, although we need a theory of quantum gravity to address such questions.

Comment: could you please explain your answer in latman

Comment: layman terms , i am not yet a college student, so i dont quite know what you are talkibg

Comment: @Mundaplackal the one-word answer is "No" and the one-sentence answer is "because of quantum mechanics and relativity." If you don't know anything about quantum mechanics and relativity, it's hard to take the explanation much further than that.

Comment: @Mundaplackal It's hard to break my answer down into simpler terms, especially when I don't know the level of your knowledge. I added a little more info, and some links that might be helpful. But if you have a specific question about anything in this answer, please let me know.